# Что такое процедурная генерация?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, терминология, процедурная-генерация

Что такое процедурная генерация и с чем её едят?

Comment: английских слов или набора латинских букв? Это две разные вещи

Comment: Я же явно написал, что процедурная генерация английских слов, а не просто случайный набор букв. Получившиеся слово может уже существовать, а может и нет. Генерация происходит по правилам британского английского языка.

Comment: *"procedural generation is a method of creating data algorithmically as opposed to manually"* [(c) Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation), так что по определению все три способа - процедурная генерация. Я так понимаю, вы под процедурной генерацией имеете в виду что-то другое?

Comment: Для меня процедурная генерация - процесс, основой для которого является сид, полностью детерменирующий результат процесса.

Comment: Под это определение опять же все три способа подходят, нет? Не совсем понимаю, какой смысл спрашивать, является ли алгоритм "процедурной генерацией", если вы не используете общепринятое определение этого слова, а понимаете под этим словом что-то свое?

Comment: Судя по всему никто не понял что именно Вы имеете ввиду под [процедурной генерацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Соответственно, никто не понял что это за `seed` и как он у Вас используется. Попробуйте указать точно что Вы хотите получить в качестве ответа (код генерации слова, код генерации случайного числа или что-то еще) и сконцентрироваться на этой части.

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, это очевидно из названия термина: это что-то, что генерируется автоматически каким-то набором функций. Например, в играх так генерируются случайные подземелья или прочие "лабиринты"...

Answer (score 1):

Автоматическое создание игрового контента с помощью алгоритмов